# Problems with CSS in HTML using Notepad++

Tags: html, css

I am trying to complete my homework for beginning web programming. I am using CSS for the first time and cannot get the link to work. I have an open css document linked to my html page.

This is everything at the top of my text before the  tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
 <!--
  New Perspectives on HTML and CSS
  Tutorial 3
  Tutorial Case

  Sunny Acres Home Page
  Author: 
  Date:   

  Filename:         home.htm
  Supporting files: photo1.jpg, modernizr-1.5.js, sa_layout.css, salogo.png,
                    sastyles.css
 -->

  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Sunny Acres</title>
  <script src="modernizr-1.5.js"></script>

  <link href=”sa_layout.css” rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” />
  <link href=”sa_styles.css” rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” />

</style>
</head>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You haven't really clearly identified what you need help with, and what specifically isn't working. Also, it's hard to make sense of what the first block of code there is supposed to mean. The only thing I notice off the bat is that, in the top block, you have `sastyles.css` and in the bottom you have `sa_styles.css`. Possibly a misnamed file?

Comment: I'm not sure what the bit at the top is, but you either have a typo in your filename, or your link href. `sastyles.css` v. `sa_styles.css`.

Comment: It is an exact copy of the exercise in my text. Sorry for the confusion, thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the mismatch of sastyles.css and sa_styles.css, I also notice a `</style>` tag on its own. Try removing this tag - I don't think that you need it here if all of your styling is taken care of by those CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

Those double quotes ” are probably not supported, check you are using both ” and "

You should use either " or '